# how to get random audio file from raw array on android?

Tags: android

```
This is my array, in the form of audio files


int[] rawQuetion = {R.raw.alikhlas, R.raw.alkafirun};// this for question
int [] rawAnswer={R.raw.jwbaliklas,R.raw.alfalaq };// this for answer
```

and this method to randomize questions

```
//fisher-yates Shuffle
public void playSoal() {
    shuffleArray(rawQuetion);
    try{
        int idx = new Random().nextInt(rawQuetion.length);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawQuetion[idx]);
        mp.start();

    }

static void shuffleArray(int[] arr)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        // Swap
        int a = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = a;
    }
}
public void audioFile() throws IOException{
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jwbaliklas);// I want get audio file from rawAnswer based rawQuestion
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        in = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        int read;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
        {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < audioBytes.length; i++) {
            audioBytes[i] = (byte) ((audioBytes[i]) & 0xFF);       }

        absNormalizedSignal = hitungFFT(audioBytes);
        AppLog.logString("===== INI DARI AUDIO FILE");


    }
```

Comment: You seem to already have code for what your question asks for. Please explain in detail the nature of your problem.

Comment: I want to take audio files of raw by random rawQuestion, I want rawAnswer selected pursuant rawQuestion

Comment: Choose a random number. Get the question based based on the random number. Get the answer based on the random number.

Comment: I am confused to write code review in this section InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jwbaliklas);

Comment: Replace `R.raw.jwbaliklas` with `rawQuetion[randomNumber]`, where `randomNumber` is a random number between 0 and `rawQuetion.length-1`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public void audioFile() throws IOException{
>         InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jwbaliklas);// I want get audio file from rawAnswer based rawQuestion
> ```

You have your answer right here: use `openRawResource()` to open a raw resource.  You don't need to hard-code specific argument values in your code.  The method takes an `int` argument.  How you determine the value to pass it entirely up to you.  For example, you can declare your `audioFile()` method to take an integer argument and pass that on to `openRawResource()`:

```
 public void audioFile(final int resid) throws IOException{
         InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resid);
```

Then, where you have your corresponding question/answer audio ids, you can pass the correct id.

Comment: I am yet to understand, what mean resid?

Comment: I build applications like quizzes

Comment: It is the name of the argument.  You can name your arguments as you wish.